# Can't highlight text in my post after opening the profile drop down menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, highlighting

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start new question/answer or edit one of your existing.
2. Type something and make sure you can highlight it with the mouse.
3. Hover over your user name and wait for the box to expand.
4. Get back to the text you typed and try to highlight it now - no matter how. (keyboard or mouse)
5. The selection disappears immediately and you effectively can't highlight anything anymore.

While annoying, it also cause I can't use the editor icons or shortcuts at all, e.g. attaching links and even make text bold if you don't know about the `**bold here**` stuff.

Comment: You're a QA engineer, aren't you?

Comment: lol @Snow most of my bosses used those skills of mine, and still using! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent catch. The code that's updating the clock in the popup is running away a little bit there (and the DOM update apparently screws with the selection) – this is fixed in the next build.

Comment: Cheers, will check it again soon. Thanks! :)